# WHERE error in MySQL with unknown column that landed with error

Tags: mysql

I have tried to use given query to get data, however got problem

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as counter , company_id
from contacts
WHERE  counter > 50
GROUP BY company_id
LIMIT 20
```

Error that I get

```
 Unknown column 'counter' in 'where clause
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than asserting the count in a `WHERE` clause, you should instead be using a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(id) AS counter, company_id
FROM contacts
GROUP BY company_id
HAVING counter > 50
-- ORDER BY <something>
LIMIT 20
```

Note that using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is not well defined.  Your query should have an `ORDER BY` clause.